# Using metamask from a local html file?

Tags: metamask

I'm building a DAPP it works fine when I host it from a server, but when the HTML file is local MetaMask gives this error:

```
MetaMask does not allow file:// protocol, use http(s)://
```

Any ideas what that means or if theres a way to get it to work? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's a browser security related thing, [more can be found here](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md).

The main excerpt:

> **Http(s) - Web Server Required**
>
> Due to browser security restrictions, we
>   can't communicate with dapps running on file://. Please use a local
>   server for development.

You have to start a local web server and access your HTML file from it.

Comment: if using vscode, using 'express host current workspace' will do the job

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your file into a local webserver.
I am using **lighttpd** as light weight webserver that recognize Metamask.

1.Go to http://lighttpd.dtech.hu/

2.Download LightTPD-1.4.35-1-IPv6-Win32-SSL.zip (or 64)

3.Extract it to local folder, i.e. C:\LightTPD

4.Run LightTPD.exe

5.Put your Dapp into C:\lighttpd\htdocs

6.Open http://localhost/ (and your Dapp web3 file)